# Python Invalid syntax in conn.commit() SQL

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping

I can't get my head around why conn.commit spits out invalid syntax as I'm trying to insert data.

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc


#ip fra host
host = "www.skat.dk" 
dest = socket.gethostbyname(host)
hdata = 'host',host,'IP:',dest


#Responseheader fra en domæne
request = urllib.Request('http://skat.dk')

request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36')

response = urllib.urlopen(request)

rdata = response.info()



#SQL Connection til localhost microsoft sql server
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                  'Server=DESKTOP-THV2IDL;'
                  'Database=host;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM host.dbo.hosts')


#Insert values
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO host.dbo.hosts
(Id, host, ip, HSTS, HPKP, XContentTypeOptions, XFrameOptions, ContentSecurityPolicy)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
""",
(49, host, dest, rdata['Strict-Transport-Security'], rdata['Public-Key-Pins'], 
rdata['X-Content-Type-Options'], rdata['X-Frame-Options'], rdata['Content-Security-Policy'], 
rdata['X-Frame-Options'])



conn.commit():
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>       PS C:\Users\Farzad\Desktop\Python> & C:/Users/Farzad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37- 
>       32/python.exe c:/Users/Farzad/Desktop/Python/Webscraping/Responseheaderinfo.py
>       File "c:/Users/Farzad/Desktop/Python/Webscraping/Responseheaderinfo.py",
>   line 47
>       conn.commit():
>          ^

Comment: You wrote a `:`

Comment: I'm also noticing you are providing 9 values when only 8 are accounted for in the query. `rdata['X-Frame-Options']` seems to be duplicated at the end of your execute call.

Comment: I removed : and added another value, removed the duplicate in the query but still get the same syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a colon appended to `conn.commit()`.

`conn.commit():` is invalid.

Comment: Is it producing the same syntax error with the same line reference? The one you have posted is definitely due to the colon.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a bracket, see the very last line below

```
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO host.dbo.hosts
(Id, host, ip, HSTS, HPKP, XContentTypeOptions, XFrameOptions, ContentSecurityPolicy)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
""",
(49, host, dest, rdata['Strict-Transport-Security'], rdata['Public-Key-Pins'], 
rdata['X-Content-Type-Options'], rdata['X-Frame-Options'], rdata['Content-Security-Policy'], 
rdata['X-Frame-Options'])) #<----extra bracket missing here
```